# What is the technical name for one sided tree traversal and which algorithms are good for it?

Tags: binary-trees, graph-traversal

Looking at the image from [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) for tree traversal
[image]
what is the name for a traversal that follows the dashed line exactly with repeating visits to obtain: F, B, A, B, D, C, D, E, D, B, F, G, I, H, I, G, F;

Also is there a well known algorithm for this task?

Comment: The caption there reads *depth first*. Algorithms are given as numbered lists: what more do you expect?

Comment: You may refer to this as the *right-hand rule* for visiting a maze. At leaves, you make a half-turn. If I am right, this can be implemented like a modified preorder traversal where you output the root node several times.

Comment: @greybeard I don't know I expect smart people on stack exchange to read and think before spamming. Read the results of a depth first nodes in the caption and compare with what I asked for. Are those the same to you?

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks I tough about mazes and actually looked it up but didn't know enough to understand it can be done by half turns. Thanks for the helpful comment. I'll lo into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for Eulerian tour on trees. You can check these:

- [Eulerian tour technique](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_tour_technique)
- [On Euler tour trees](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/18369)

Comment: THANK YOU! Really..